# disable selection of the spinner

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

How could I disable selection of the spinner

```
<mvvmcross.droid.support.v7.appcompat.widget.MvxAppCompatSpinner
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:textColor="@color/primary_text"   
  local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/spinner_template"
  local:MvxBind="ItemsSource StudentList; ItemSelected StudentType" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind directly to the Enabled property on the Spinner:

```
local:MvxBind="ItemsSource StudentList; ItemSelected StudentType; Enabled IsEnabled"
```

The same goes for any other public property. Although most of them will be OneWay bindings, which shouldn't matter in this case though.

You ViewModel property would look like any other property:

```
private bool _isEnabled;
public bool IsEnabled
{
    get { return _isEnabled; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _isEnabled, value); }
}
```

Then when you need to enable/disable the control:

```
IsEnabled = true;
```

Comment: How do you enable in the ViewModel?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<mvvmcross.droid.support.v7.appcompat.widget.MvxAppCompatSpinner
  android:id=@+id/spinner1
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:textColor="@color/primary_text"   
  android:enabled="false"
  android:clickable="false"
  local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/spinner_template"
  local:MvxBind="ItemsSource StudentList; ItemSelected StudentType" />
```

To enable, in your activity/fragment try this.

```
  MvxAppCompatSpinner spinner1 = (MvxAppCompatSpinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
  spinner1.setEnabled(true);
  spinner1.setClickable(true);
```

Comment: how do you enable it programatically then?